# Height for tableView.headerView(forSection: 0) is nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to change the height of the header view as the user scrolls following [this tutorial](https://michiganlabs.com/ios/development/2016/05/31/ios-animating-uitableview-header/). However, when I try to access `self.songsTable.headerView(forSection: 0)?.frame.size.height` (so I can update the height of the header view), the value is nil and the debugger tells me "header view has no height". I created my header view programmatically using `heightForHeaderInSection` and `viewForHeaderInSection`.

**Code**

```
class SongsViewController {
var currentHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 136

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        //Throws error
        guard let currentHeaderHeight = self.songsTable.headerView(forSection: 0)?.frame.size.height else {
            print("header view has no height")
            return
        }
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return currentHeaderHeight
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Screen.width, height: maxHeaderHeight)
        return headerView
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit hard to debug without seeing the complete code. Some things that come to mind - What's currentHeaderHeight? Could it be 0? Do you have any sections (numberOfSections)? Is your debugger printing that because songsTable.headerView(forSection: 0) is nil?

Comment: @cloudcal I've updated my code. currentHeaderHeight is initially set to 136.  `numberOfSections` is 1. I'm not sure why `songsTable.headerView(forSection: 0)` is nill even though I can see the header on the simulator

Comment: @Alex , hi, did you find out reason for this nil issue?

Comment: Have anyone found a solution to this. I'm sitting in it right now 

Answer (score 0):

This may just be missing in your code snippet, but have you set up your viewController as the TableViewDataSource?

```
class SongsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        songsTable.dataSource = self
    }

    // ... the rest of your code ...
}
```

Comment: yupp I have done that. Maybe I'm calling the wrong func to get the header view for the section?